# How to avoid text go below the thumbnail with css

Tags: css, text, inline, word-wrap

I have posts list with thumbnails.

I'm trying to prevent the title from going under the image.

I tried `white-space: normal` but it didn't effect the text here. I also tried `float: left` and `Display:inline` nothing helped to keep the title beside the image.

[image]

CODE CSS&HTML:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  background-color:white;
}
li{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 325px;
  border-bottom:1px solid @border-color;
  padding:10px;
  white-space: normal;
  
}
img{ 
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
}
.post-title{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.post-title a{
  white-space: normal;
  color:@breadcrumbs-current-color;
}
.post-title p{
  margin-bottom:0;
  color:gray;
  font-size:11px;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a><img src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png"/ ></a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Street Dance Moves Comically Illustrated
      <p>200 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a><img src="http://www.ionnic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/e/becable.png"/></a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Hello World
      <p>80 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick solution is to use `max-width` and remove `vertical-align`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 325px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid@border-color;

padding: 10px;
  white-space: normal;
}
img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.post-title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.post-title a {
  white-space: normal;
  color: @breadcrumbs-current-color;

}
.post-title p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Street Dance Moves Comically Illustrated
      <p>200 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="http://www.ionnic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/e/becable.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Hello World
      <p>80 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

But i suggest to go with `display: table` technique:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
li {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 325px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid@border-color;

padding: 10px;
  white-space: normal;
}
img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.post-title {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 5px;
  max-width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.post-title a {
  white-space: normal;
  color: @breadcrumbs-current-color;

}
.post-title p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 11px;
}
li > a {
  width: 90px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Street Dance Moves Comically Illustrated
      <p>200 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="http://www.ionnic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/e/becable.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Hello World
      <p>80 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <img src="http://www.ionnic.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/e/becable.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="post-title">
      <a>Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World
      <p>80 view</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```